# How do I load a prerecorded movie in my camera roll using GPUImage?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, gpuimage

I tried to use the following code to load a movie from the "Camera Roll" folder, but I don't know which URL I should give.

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"filename" withExtension:@"mp4"];
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
```

How can I find the filename of a movie in my photo album?

Comment: Are you trying to let the user pick a video from the camera roll or do you have a specific preset video that you want to use?

Comment: No.  I would like to traverse all movies exist in my photo album.  This line should be one line in the loop.  However, I don't know the absolute path of movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the assets in the camera roll directly you could use the [assets library framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html). The following code should log the path to each movie in the camera roll:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
ALAssetsGroupType assetTypes = ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos | ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupLibrary | ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream;
NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [NSMutableArray array];

[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:assetTypes usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    // store the asset groups in an array
    if (group)
    {
        [assetGroups addObject:group];
    }
    // once all the groups are stored we can access the individual assets
    else
    {
        for (ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup in assetGroups)
        {
            [assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
            {
                if (result && [[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
                {
                    NSURL *assetURL = [[result defaultRepresentation] url];
                    NSLog(@"%@", [assetURL path]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}
failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
{
    // handle error
}];
```